# Embed PDF in Chrome with Toolbar Collapsed

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf

When embedding a PDF in Chrome, there's a sidebar on the left that shows thumbnails of different pages. Clicking on the three horizontal lines on the top-left collapses this navigation pane. I would like to embed a PDF in a web page such that when it is loaded in Chrome, the navigation pane is collapsed, but the toolbar (including the three horizontal lines that allow the navigation pane to expand) is still there.

Example code:

```
<!-- #toolbar=0&navpanes=0 -->
<iframe src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0" style="width: 550px; height: 850px;"></iframe>

<!-- #toolbar=0 -->
<iframe src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf#toolbar=0" style="width: 550px; height: 850px;"></iframe>

<!-- #navpanes=0 -->
<iframe src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf#navpanes=0" style="width: 550px; height: 850px;"></iframe>
```

The output of these 3 combinations of URL parameters:
[image]

As you can see, the two versions on the left have no toolbars at all, whereas the final one on the right has both the one-page PDF as well as the thumbnail. If you were to click the 3 horizontal lines, it would collapse the navigation pane, which is my desired outcome.

[image]

Is there a URL parameter that I can use to collapse the navigation pane, but keep the toolbar at the top? Or is there some way to click on the 3 horizontal lines using JavaScript (or something else) that would auto-collapse it for me?

Comment: @KJ Right - do you know of any way to get the Chrome version to act the way I've described?

Comment: Yeah that matches what I'm seeing as well. I tried to go the JavaScript route, I can select/modify the contents of an iFrame, but I can't interact with the PDF viewer itself unfortunately.